# Rally: Query Filtered to Specific Tags

Tags: dojo, rally

I am writing a custom app for Rally and I would like to filter the data to stories with specific tags.  So far I haven't found a way to write the correct syntax to achieve this purpose.  Here's an example of a standard query that I would include in the cardboardConfig:

```
var query = new rally.sdk.util.Query('SomeField = "Some Value"');
```

This works well enough when trying to query a field that contains a single value, but this doesn't appear to work on tags since tags are arrays -- assuming I am even referencing the correct field name.  I tried all of the following without success:

```
var query = new rally.sdk.util.Query('Tags = "Some Value"');
var query = new rally.sdk.util.Query('Tags contains "Some Value"');
var query = new rally.sdk.util.Query('Tag = "Some Value"');
var query = new rally.sdk.util.Query('Tag contains "Some Value"');
var query = new rally.sdk.util.Query('Tags = {"Some Value"}');
var query = new rally.sdk.util.Query('Tags contains {"Some Value"}');
var query = new rally.sdk.util.Query('Tag = {"Some Value"}');
var query = new rally.sdk.util.Query('Tag contains {"Some Value"}');

var SearchTags = { "Some Value" };
var query = new rally.sdk.util.Query('Tags = SearchTags');

var SearchTags = { "Some Value" };
var query = new rally.sdk.util.Query('Tags contains SearchTags');
```

What is the correct field name and operator for filtering the data to specific tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = new rally.sdk.util.Query('Tags.Name Contains "Some Value");
```

This works for tags, but won't currently work for all collections.

Comment: Quick question.  If I wanted to get everything that does not contain this tag, what would the syntax be?  I tried Not Contains, but this didn't appear to work.

Comment: Unfortunately Rally's WSAPI does not support 'not contains' at this time.