# how can I obtain all tags in rally api

Tags: rally

We use tags to identify our completed user stories.  Now we have a need to automatic that process by querying tags and generate a list of user stories that associate to that tag.

I have found the following link very useful:

[Rally: Query Filtered to Specific Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748318/rally-query-filtered-to-specific-tags)

However, I'd like to somehow query Rally so I can get a list of all the tags first so users has the freedom to pick a tag they want to query.  Any idea how to accomplish that?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the AppSDK 1.0? That is what is referenced in that post.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SDK 1.0 you can use the code below to get all allowable tags. All you should have to do it supply a function named "callback" to handle your results.

```
queryConfig = { 
    type : 'defect',
    key : 'defects',
    query: '(Archived = false)',
    fetch: 'Name,Priority'
  };

  var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('__WORKSPACE_OID__', 
                           '__PROJECT_OID__',
                           '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__', 
                           '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__'); 
  rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConfig, callback);
```

Comment: (Using RallyDataSource and specifying a type of 'tag')